# Sending RPC-JSON Commands to Bitcoin Peers

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, peers

Is it possible to send some commands to Bitcoin Peers? for example `decoderawtransaction` command?

Comment: There are plenty of libraries that will decode a raw transaction as well, you don't have to go to a full node to do that.

Comment: it is not the main reason, it is just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RPC interface of most nodes is password protected, so you can't send RPC commands to an arbitrary peer on the network. If you run your own node though, you can set it up with a password and the the RPC protocol to issue commands.